# Como passar variável para arquivo PHP no Shell Script

Tags: php, linux, shell-script

como posso fazer para passar uma variavel para um arquivo php em um shell script, estou tentando fazer dessa forma abaixo, sem sucesso.

```
php -f complete.php?login=$1
```

Answer (score 1):

Existirá uma variável `$argv` que será um *array* com os valores passados via CLI, mas não da forma que você fez. Basta passar o valor como argumento do *script*:

```
$ php -f complete.php teste
```

Assim, se fizer o valor de `$argv` será `['teste']`.

Veja mais na documentação oficial: [Array de argumentos passados para o script](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/reserved.variables.argv.php).